# recaptcha issue Firebase phone authentication react-native error {Recaptcha verification failed - SITE_MISMATCH}

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, recaptcha

Have racked my head on this ... {code:auth/catcha-check-failed, message:Recaptcha verification failed - SITE_MISMATCH} recaptcha resolves properly complete with stats in the recaptcha console, but for some reason Firebase returns the above error for which there is no documentation on what the problem/configuration-issue is or is causing it.

Have verified the SHA-1, ensured the domain is whitelisted but still refuses to resolve for SMS Phone Authentication.

This is a release variant on Android phone and not a debug or emulator. Anyone encountered this before? Is there a specific configuration I may have skipped?